# how to add vertical and horizontal divider in table layout?

Tags: android, tablelayout

I am trying to create a screen which displays students and their corresponding marks in different subjects in table format. How to create vertical and horizontal divider?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code after your each row items

for Horizontal line in XML

```
<View android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:background="@android:color/red" 
  android:layout_height="2dp" />
```

for vertical line in XML

```
<View android:layout_width="2dp"
  android:background="@android:color/red" 
  android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for how to create a border around your table rows and around the table layout . and not divider.
you have to create a drawable to serve as a border,and then you set it as a background.
Hers a solution :

**res/drawable/shape_table.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape= "rectangle">
   <solid android:color="#000000"/>
   <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000"/>
</shape>
```

**Your Layout.xml**

```
<TableLayout
     ....>
     <TableRow
         ....
          android:background="@drawable/shape_table">

           <TextView
            ...
              android:background="@drawable/shape_table"
              />

           <TextView
            ...
              android:background="@drawable/shape_border"
               />
     </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

If you are looking for a divider you can use 
Vertical :

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="#c0c0c0"/>
```

Horizontal :

```
<View
        android:layout_width="2dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#c0c0c0"/>
```